# Open a bootstrap modal within an opened modal

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Hello friends I just started review of an old project in which they have used bootstrap 2.0.... I need to add some specifications to it and so... i need to get data in first modal in  which I need to open a new modal to get another data (like stacking one upon another) without the first modal being closed. After getting the data from second modal i need to redirect it to the first modal. Is this possible?

Since I'm a newbie I cant be sure if its possible to implement and so I just came up to stack overflow....